# Users unable to login after migration of bugzilla from one machine to other

Tags: bugzilla

I have recently migrated the bugzilla from one machine to other following https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/moving.html document. I have cross-verified users list, bugs, attachments etc, all are in place. But only users are not able to login post migration.
OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Is there any clue, how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using below command to create empty database fixes the problem.

> **mysql -u root -p -e "CREATE DATABASE bugs;**